# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "0" CONTEXT: COPY stateprovince, line 1, column stateprovinceid: "0" SQL state: 22P02

Tags: postgresql

Im creating this table

CREATE TABLE StateProvince(
StateProvinceID SERIAL,
StateProvinceCode char(3) NOT NULL,
CountryRegionCode varchar(3) NOT NULL,

when i import the data from a csv file

SELECT 'Copying data into Person.StateProvince';
copy Person.StateProvince FROM 'C:\Users\Ernesto Cabrera\Desktop\Prueba\StateProvidence.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;

these appears

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "0"
CONTEXT:  COPY stateprovince, line 1, column stateprovinceid: "0"
SQL state: 22P02

Comment: To your question add the complete `COPY` command you are using. At a guess you are not including `WITH CSV` and are importing as straight text.